# Json To Angular

Tags: python, html, json, angular, microsoft-graph-api

I am using MSGraph Api with Python as a backend and angular as a frontend to pull data but given output is showing in json format with all metadata i want to show specific data from it. How can i do that.

Python Code:

```
@app.route('/getChannel',methods=['GET','POST'])
def Channels():
    token = _get_token_from_cache(app_config.SCOPE)
    if not token:
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    channel_data = requests.get(  
        app_config.ChannelURL,
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']},
        ).json()['value']
    return render_template('team.html',result=channel_data)
```

json output

```
[
    {
        "createdDateTime": "2021-05-08T04:47:39.67Z",
        "description": null,
        "displayName": "General",
        "email": "",
        "id": "19:c9f316c845794a21a1ff2ba50be2bb1e@thread.tacv2",
        "isFavoriteByDefault": null,
        "membershipType": "standard",
        "webUrl": 
    },
    {
        "createdDateTime": "2021-05-08T05:00:11.348Z",
        "description": null,
        "displayName": "Developement",
        "email": "",
        "id": "19:da1aff92f51f416c9390881e2fa70716@thread.tacv2",
        "isFavoriteByDefault": true,
        "membershipType": "standard",
        "webUrl": 
    },
    {
        "createdDateTime": "2021-05-09T15:16:46.27Z",
        "description": "testing",
        "displayName": "channel1",
        "email": "",
        "id": "19:e81758e4858e4f598d31214282d6c100@thread.tacv2",
        "isFavoriteByDefault": false,
        "membershipType": "standard",
        "webUrl": 
    }
]
```

Comment: What is the specific data you want to show & how are you fetching it on angular side? Please add code snippet or some sandbox to check implementation

Comment: I want to show only "displayName" but still working on angular part (This is my first trial with Python and Angular so not sure how i connect python and angular code)

Comment: You want to show displayName on UI??